# Open web page in UIWebView after click on the button

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, uibutton

I need help. I have two button, and I need each button to open a different web page in my UIWebView (for example: button1 open website apple.com, button2 open google.com). I can not find any tutorial that would help me. Thx for help **(I use Storyboard)**.

There is my code, but something is wrong, because I see only a black screen (after click on the button)

**TabulkaViewController.m**

```
    UIButton *myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    myButton.frame = CGRectMake(10, 240, 300, 35);
    [myButton setTitle:@"Buttonone" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(myButtonClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview: myButton];
}
-(void) myButtonClick:(NSString *)myString
{   
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.apple.com/"];
    WebViewController *viewWeb = [[WebViewController alloc] initWithURL:url andTitle:@"Apple"];
    [self presentViewController:viewWeb animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

**WebViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface WebViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate>
{
NSURL *theURL;
NSString *theTitle;
IBOutlet UINavigationItem *webTitle;
}
- (id)initWithURL:(NSURL *)url;
- (id)initWithURL:(NSURL *)url andTitle:(NSString *)string;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *viewWeb;
@end
```

**WebViewController.m**

```
#import "WebViewController.h"
@implementation WebViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    webTitle.title = theTitle;
    NSURLRequest *requestObject = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:theURL];
    [_viewWeb loadRequest:requestObject];
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}
- (id)initWithURL:(NSURL *)url andTitle:(NSString *)string {
    if( self = [super init] ) {
        theURL = url;
        theTitle = string;
    }
    return self;
}
-(id)initWithURL:(NSURL *)url {
    return [self initWithURL:url andTitle:nil];
}
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    _viewWeb.delegate = nil;
    [_viewWeb stopLoading];
}
@end
```

Comment: Looks to me like you're not actually adding the webview as a subview anywhere? You're loading the request but not presenting it on screen.

Comment: He is, using presentViewController:animated:completion:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When working with storyboard, it would help if you upload your project file somewhere.

But from experience you need to set your webView delegate to your class **WebViewController**

you can do it by adding this in your viewDidLoad:

```
self.webView.delegate = self;
```

then you must implement the **shouldStartLoadWithRequest**  delegate call, this is a good start.

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{ 
    return YES;
}
```

let me know if this fixes it.

**EDIT:** 
after checking your project, change **WebViewController**->**viewDidLoad** to this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // init webview
    _viewWeb = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];

    _viewWeb.delegate = self;

    // add it to this controller's view
    [self.view addSubview:_viewWeb];

    webTitle.title = theTitle;
    NSURLRequest *requestObject = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:theURL];

    [self.viewWeb loadRequest:requestObject];
}
```

your _viewWeb wasn't initialized as I suspected, See my comments on how to initialize it and how to add it to your **WebViewController**

**EDIT2:**
Added constraints in for the web view to take full screen, I recommend you read-up about auto layout in apple docs

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // init webview
    _viewWeb = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];

    _viewWeb.delegate = self;

    // add it to this controller's view
    [self.view addSubview:_viewWeb];


    // add constraints
    NSDictionary* dict = @{@"viewWeb":_viewWeb};
    _viewWeb.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    NSArray* constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-0-[viewWeb]-0-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:dict];
    [self.view addConstraints:constraints];
    constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-0-[viewWeb]-0-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:dict];
    [self.view addConstraints:constraints];

    webTitle.title = theTitle;
    NSURLRequest *requestObject = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:theURL];

    [self.viewWeb loadRequest:requestObject];
}
```

Comment: When I use self.viewWeb = self; in WebViewController (in viewDidLoad), I have warning: incompatible pointer types assigning to UIWebView from WebViewController :/

Comment: sorry my bad, it should be: self.webView.delegate = self, I'll edit the answer

Comment: did you add _viewWeb to your view? step through your code WebViewController->viewDidLoad, and make sure _viewWeb is not nil. If you can upload your project somewhere I'll take a quick look and see what's going on.

Comment: I can send you project tomorrow, ok?

Comment: sure no problem, follow me on twitter @mikeMTOL and I'll PM you my email.

Comment: Ok i follow you now (my twitter is @Aliencz)